# I need an .htaccess rule for rewriting the url from example.com/xyz to xyz.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a that has several applications running in a subfolder that I want to move to a subdomain and replace the current site with a new website but still allow the old applications to be found at the previous url for example

current: mysite.com/application/page1.aspx

What I want to do is move this application to application.mysite.com/page1.aspx

I need an .htaccess rewrite rule that does two things

1. will still allow someone to goto mysite.com/application/page1.aspx
   and get to the application
2. Keep the URL displayed on the page as
   mysite.com/application/page1.aspx hiding the fact that its a
   subdomain.

Its not so important to hide the subdomain as it is to keep Google happy finding the content on those pages where it has always been.

NOTE: This new main site is a wordpress site.

Here's what I have in htaccess now

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com/foldername$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^adminpgm/(.*)$ http://SUBDOMAIN.mysite.com/adminpgm/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule . /foldername/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: For one thing the new site is a Wordpress site, so I think there are going to be other issues... But I edited the original post to show what I have now

Answer (score 0):

Because Wordpress also uses urls with subfolders this is going to be very hard to automate (if you use pretty urls, every post, page, category, etc could be shown as a subfolder).

If you know exactly which applications you're moving, you could do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(application1|application2|another-one|application4)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Just put all the application folder names in the first rule, separated by pipes (`|`)

About SEO:
"Its not so important to hide the subdomain as it is to keep Google happy finding the content on those pages where it has always been."

As long as you redirect with an [R=301] flag, Google will know that the content has moved and there is no problem at all. Over time, Google will start showing the subdomain in the search results instead of the old URL, which I'd say is preferrable over having to support old urls forever.